# Making a scrollable tooltip in d3 pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

I am using [d3pie](https://github.com/benkeen/d3pie) with d3.js. When I hover over the pie I see the tooltip with the data but the rest of the data is cut off/ hidden because the data is way too long.

I want to show a scrollable list of gateways when clicked on the pie just like a tooltip.

here is my code.

```
var pie = new d3pie("gateway-datasources-status-chart", {
        size: {
            canvasHeight: 300,
            canvasWidth: 300
        },
        data: {
            content: [
                { label: "Online", value: online_gateway, lists: online_gateway_datasources },
                { label: "Offline", value: offline_gateway, lists: offline_gateway_datasources }
            ]
        },
        "tooltips": {
            "enabled": true,
            "type": "placeholder",
            "string": "{label}: {lists}",
            "styles": {
                "backgroundColor": "#040404",
                "borderRadius": 5
            }
        },
        callbacks: {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you have a working fiddle ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pgnv61f4/#&togetherjs=4ftcwNKMNA

Comment: Please add a sample where you can show the actual problem.  Where data is large.

Comment: You cannot make it scrollable since it is an svg text element.You can try adding a text box instead of that.

Comment: I have tried to print this value `lists: ["asd","asd","asd","asd"]` in the tool tip but it is not printing. Can u assume that it has a huge data and think of something?

Comment: I was thiniking of adding a new  div element onClick in the pie and make the div scrollable but i am stuck on that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating a div as svg doesn't allow scroll. Here is an example : http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369

Basically add a div :

```
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")   
    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
    .style("opacity", 0);
```

Then on mouseover, move the div to where the mouse is and change the div's text :

```
 .on("mouseover", function(d) {     
            div.transition()        
                .duration(200)      //so it fades in
                .style("opacity", .9);      
            div .html(formatTime(d.date) + "<br/>"  + d.close)  
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
            })                  
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
            div.transition()        
                .duration(500)      //so it fades out
                .style("opacity", 0);   
        });
```

To do this on click :

```
pieChart.on("click",function(d){
//show tooltip
})
```

Comment: if you want multiple divs so the divs stay in one place, just change opacity of associated div to 1 on mouseover (part of the pie chart) and on mouseout change opacity to 0

Comment: will it work onClick event too ? http://d3pie.org/#docs I want to implement it in `callbacks.onClickSegment`

Comment: yes. Just call the click event when you click the pie chart. Ill add to answer